# How to prove the brachistochrone to be Isochronous

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

When I was reading the calculus of Variations chapter in *Classical Mechanics* by John R. Taylor, he mentioned that cart rolling back and forth on cycloid-shaped track are exactly isochronous (period perfectly independent of amplitude). As I was trying to solve this by the original integral, I find it hard to compute and the normal Casio type calculator cannot solve it as well, also I sought help from websites like Integral Calculator, the result function is not independent of the starting angle I set. Can someone help me, great great thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your efforts?

Comment: $x = a(\theta -\sin \theta); y = a(1-\cos\theta)$

Comment: $\t = \int^{\pi} _{\phi} \sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2}{2g(y-y_0)}}\cdot d\theta$

Comment: $ = \sqrt{\frac{a}{g}}\int^{\pi}_{\phi} \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\cos\phi-cos\theta}} d\theta $

Comment: I can see the result when$\phi \in[0,\pi)$ the integral is roughly equal to $\pi$, but they are not the same.

Comment: Try editing that information into the question, which is where people will be looking for it.

Comment: Try looking up "tautochrone".

Comment: Thanks I found steps in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TautochroneProblem.html it's just integration techniques